# How to debug WCF dataservice

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dataservice

I have a written dataservice for my windowsphone application and i'm trying to savechanges to this dataservice. To do this i call `BeginSaveChanges`:

```
    Context.AddToMeasurements(temp);
    Context.BeginSaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch, SaveChangesComplete, Context);
```

The callback of this function returns an error when `EndSaveChanges` is called.

```
private void SaveChangesComplete(IAsyncResult result)
{
    // use a dispatcher to make sure the async void 
    // returns on the right tread.
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {

        DataServiceResponse WriteOperationResponse = null;

        Context = result.AsyncState as MeasurementEntities;

        try
        {
             WriteOperationResponse = Context.EndSaveChanges(result);
             Debug.WriteLine("Batch State:");
             Debug.WriteLine(WriteOperationResponse.BatchStatusCode);
        }
        catch (DataServiceRequestException ex)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    });        
}
```

The Error the endsavechanges returns:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WP80.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WP80.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WP80.DLL
An exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WP80.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An error occurred while processing this request.
```

I would like to see some more detailed information about these errors, or if someone knows what they mean that also would be appreiciated, but how can I accomplish (more details on the dataservice) within visual studio?

ps, i have allready added:

```
config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
```

and

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
```

to my dataservice.

please help :)

edit:

---

When i remove the Try construction and just execute a EndSaveChanges method. I can read the innerExeptions, which is:

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Measurement' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

any idea's what this means?

Comment: you can attach your debugger to w3wp.exe for debuggind wcf services

Comment: Is there a guide in how to do so? oh btw, the dataservice is not running on the same desktop as visual studio.

Comment: then how can you debug it?

Comment: I can't right now, thats why I've asked this question. It should be possible to move the dataservice to a local dataservice. ill have a look at that later. But for now, visual studio throws me some errormessages when I try to endSaveChanges, and I don't know where to look.

Comment: Okay, i have got a little further and ive updated my anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Measurement' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

it means that you are not passing any value to `Measurement` column and it is a mandatory field in the database. You need to pass value to it.

Comment: But that is just what i want. I want to insert a measurement without specifing the primary key. I have the database set to increment and seed. So that is the measurmentid value isnt specified, it is automaticly inserted at the bottom of the table. So is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Oke, i think i solved it. I had set my database side to be autoincrement and primary key. I had not commited this change to the wcf data service.